# How can I search and replace a match a specific number of times in a string in Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I search and replace a match with specific number of times using `s///;`. For example:

```
$string="abcabdaaa";
```

I want to replace `a` with `i` in `$string` n times. How can I do that? n is an integer provided by user.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are doing? You have a bit of an XY problem here. Tell use the real problem you are trying to solve instead of the potential solution you think is the answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

The simple answer probably doesn't do want you want.

```
my $str = 'aaaa';
$str =~ s/a/a_/ for 1..2;
print $str, "\n"; # a__aaa. But you want a_a_aa, right?
```

You need to count the replacements yourself, and act accordingly:

```
$str = 'aaaa';
my $n = 0;
$str =~ s/(a)/ ++$n > 2 ? $1 : 'a_' /ge;
print $str, "\n";
```

See the FAQ, [How do I change the Nth occurrence of something?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-change-the-Nth-occurrence-of-something%3f) for related examples.

Answer (score 6):

Just substitute $n times:

```
$string =~ s/a/i/ for 1..$n;
```

This will do it.
More general solution would be global substitution with counter:

```
my $i = 0; # count the substitutions made
$string =~ s/(a)/ ++$i > $n ? $1 : "i" /ge;
```

Comment: hi but am facing problem when am replacing by $s="***ab***c"; $s=~s{\*}{\*\n} for 1..2; print$s; it replaces first * by *\n and the rest it ignores... why? "*\n" **ab***c

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need smth like this:

my $i = 0; 

$str =~ s/(\\*)/ ++$i > $n ? $1 : "*\n" /ge;

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any flag that would do that. I'd simply use a loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
   $string =~ s/a/i/;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

```
$str1=join('i',split(/a/,$str,$n));
```

Comment: i beleive this would be more efficient then simply doing $string =~ s/a/i/ for 1..$n;

Comment: you may be right about the easy to understand. but as for efficiency
using s/a/i/ for 1..$n will take O(n*m). while using split will take O(n).

Comment: This also avoids the problem encountered when the replacement string matches the match expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do based on the comment you made to [eugene y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161385/how-can-i-search-and-replace-a-match-a-specific-number-of-times-in-a-string-in-pe/2161479#2161479)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $string = '***ab***c';
my $n = 3;

1 while $n -- and $string =~ s/\*([^\n])/*\n$1/;

print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
*
*
*
ab***c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
sub substitute_n {
  my $n = shift;
  my $pattern = shift;
  my $replace = shift;
  local $_ = shift;

  my $i = 1;
  s{($pattern)} {
    $i++ <= $n ? eval qq{"$replace"} : $1;
  }ge;

  $_;
}
```

You can then write

```
my $s = "***ab***c";

print "[", substitute_n(2, qr/\*/, '$1\n', $s), "]\n";
```

to get the following output:

```
[*
*
*ab***c]
```

Comment: Won't the output actually be: [*\n\n**ab***c] ?  It will match on the first * on each iteration.

Comment: I posted runnable, working code. You don't have to take my word for it! :-)